# pandas create a column and assign values to it from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary looks like this,

```
{"regions":[
   {"name": "South America", "code": "SA01,SA02,SA03"},
   {"name": "Asia Pacific", "code": "AP01,AP02,AP03"}
]}
```

I have a df looks like this,

```
id    code
1     SA01
2     SA02
3     SA03
4     AP01
5     AP02
6     AP03
```

I like to create a column `region` in `df` whose values will be based on the `code` values in `regions`, so the result will look like,

```
id    code    region
1     SA01    South America
2     SA02    South America
3     SA03    South America
4     AP01    Asia Pacific
5     AP02    Asia Pacific
6     AP03    Asia Pacific
```

I am wondering whats the best way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could redefine your dictionary (`d` here) to have an individual `code:region` entry for each code that appears in the strings and use it to map the values in the `code` column:

```
d_ = {code:sd['name'] for sd in d['regions'] for code in sd['code'].split(',')} 
# {'SA01': 'South America', 'SA02': 'South America', 'SA03': 'South America',...
df['region'] = df.code.map(d_)
```

---

```
print(df)

   id  code         region
0   1  SA01  South America
1   2  SA02  South America
2   3  SA03  South America
3   4  AP01   Asia Pacific
4   5  AP02   Asia Pacific
5   6  AP03   Asia Pacific
```

Answer (score 1):

This example takes your current dataset without any modifications. I'm sure that this can be refined by someone with more pandas experience.

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {"regions":[
{"name": "South America", "code": "SA01,SA02,SA03"},
{"name": "Asia Pacific", "code": "AP01,AP02,AP03"}
]}

col_names_regions = ['code', 'region name']
df_regions = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names_regions)

for key, values in mydict.items():
  for value in values:
    codes = value.get('code')
    name = value.get('name')
    for code in codes.split(','):
      df1 = {'code': code, 'region name': name}
      df_regions = df_regions.append(df1, ignore_index=True)

print (df_regions)
# output 
   code    region name
0  SA01  South America
1  SA02  South America
2  SA03  South America
3  AP01   Asia Pacific
4  AP02   Asia Pacific
5  AP03   Asia Pacific
```